# How do I download the command-line emacs instead of the GUI one?

Tags: command-line, emacs

I used `sudo apt-get install emacs` to download emacs. I expected the command-line emacs to start when I ran `emacs` but instead the GUI emacs started.

How can I download the command-line emacs?

Comment: Please consider changing your accept from the highly unwise answer that falsely implies dragging in all of the X library dependencies of the ordinary emacs package is necessary, to one of those which answers your *actual question* by showing how to install a headless version of emacs without all those unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The command-line emacs is installed along with the GUI.
To run it, use the `-nw` option. An explanation from `man emacs`:

> **-nw**, **--no-window-system**
> Tell  Emacs  not  to  use its special interface to X.  If you use
> this switch when invoking Emacs from an xterm(1) window,  display
> is done in that window.

So run the following command to use emacs from the command-line:

```
emacs -nw
```

[image]

If you don't want to have to type `emacs -nw`, you could create an alias.
Put the following line in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias emacs="emacs -nw"
```

You can add this alias in one line by using I/O Redirection::

```
echo alias emacs=\"emacs -nw\" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This answer only covers **running** non-X emacs. This does not explain how to **download** emacs that is only for command line.

Comment: @user2943160 What do you mean? This answer starts out with the sentence "The command-line emacs is installed along with the GUI". We know from the question that the OP already knows how to install it.

Comment: @JonBentley hello from your necropost comment. This answer still doesn't cover a non-windowed (that is, no support for system windowed operation) installation of emacs, though such a thing isn't particularly necessary given, yes, the rest of the content.

Comment: @user2943160 This is a Q&A site, not a forum, so there is no concept of a "necropost". The value is in the question and the answers, not in the timing. I don't think the OP particularly cares whether or not there is no support for a windowed vesrion, so long as they can run it on the command line (and even if we interpret the question title in that way, a frame challenge would be valid given the OP's underlying objective). This answer is perfectly fine as it is in addressing the root of the question, and is a valuable alternative to the other options.

Comment: This is a very poor answer, because when the ordinary emacs package is installed via apt on a headless system not normally used with X, it will not only unnecessarily install the X version of emacs, it will install all of the X client libraries that are dependencies of that - which is a *huge* amount of unnecessary installation.

Comment: @JonBentley a three years later combative comment isn't particularly positive. As is evidenced by the votes on this page (my comment, belacqua's answer), the sentiment of my comment is accurate.

Answer (score 113):

That would be `emacs-nox` I believe.  This is the meta-package that currently points to `emacs24-nox` .

> Description: The GNU Emacs editor
>   (without X support)

So, just as before but with that package:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs-nox
```

or alternatively

```
sudo apt-get install emacs24-nox
```

---

For cases like this, where you wonder what's in what package, try this :

```
apt-cache search ^emacs
```

then

```
 apt-cache show <whateverpackage>
```

Comment: "sudo apt-get install emacs24-nox" did work for me.

Comment: Stephan - try `emacs23-nox`. Its still a big package at 26MB download/78MB on disk.

Comment: This is closer to what I believe the accepted answer should be.  Often Emacs is desired on servers which do not need the resource clutter of the full emacs distribution installed.

Comment: Installing nox required 7 dependencies for me on a fresh system. Without nox, it would've installed 122.

Comment: It's too bad that this great big thing doesn't include a decent Editor.  (Grinning, Running, and Ducking)

Comment: ^^ go up please.

Answer (score 6):

If possible, delete the old version of emacs, then reinstall the version without X. The `*` on the end of the command is important and will save you from a world of pain.

```
apt-get remove emacs*
apt-get install emacs-nox
```

You can also specify the version of emacs without X to install, such as `emacs23-nox` or `emacs24.nox` rather than installing the alias package.

Sure, you can mess with bash aliasing or pass in `-nw`, but when you use sudo, or emacs is summoned by git, you'll see that X window once again.

Comment: installing emacs-nox will remove the other package.

Comment: In `apt` removing packages with wildcard `*` may cause serious problem on system If you don't read its output and just aggree with it.

Answer (score 1):

You already have installed it.

Just run emacs with:

```
emacs -nw
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I accidentally downgraded a post without intending to. `emacs -nw` is the correct option.

I just get tired of the vi/emacs flame warz. If the original post didn't mention vi, then mentioning vi doesn't help.

Besides, emacs has a vi mode in it `- viper-mode`.

Comment: No, that is *not* the correct answer.  The question is about *installing* a non-gui version, installing the huge gui version and all of its unecessary gui dependencies is not a reasonable solution, when in fact it's possible to do exactly what the question seeks.