# Emacs package without GTK

Tags: server, apt, package-management, console, emacs

Is there, in the "regular" Debian/Ubuntu repositories, a package for emacs without GTK support? I'm on a server and would like to install only the console version, without a dozen of unneeded graphical libs.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [How to download the command-line-emacs not the GUI one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23645/how-to-download-the-command-line-emacs-not-the-gui-one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `emacs23-nox` is the right package for you.